# How are Java system properties derived from the host?

Tags: java, jvm, environment-variables, jvm-hotspot

There is a set of system properties available by default in a JVM, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022320/full-list-of-default-java-system-properties). Where in Hotspot are they derived?

Properties like `user.home` must be determined differently on different OSes, and I'm looking for the code that does this.

Comment: This code is in the JVM. I suggest you look at the source in the OpenJDK.

Comment: I know it's in OpenJDK but I haven't been able to find it yet. Hotspot is a ... pretty big codebase and I don't know its organisation well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know it's in OpenJDK but I haven't been able to find it yet

A common approach is to check out the OpenJDK source tree from the mercurial repository and use some sort of a `find` command to look for occurrences of what you are looking for. In that case, a simple

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep "user\.home" {} \; -print
```

leads to `./jdk/src/windows/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c` (and similar files for other operating systems, like `./jdk/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c`) where there is a function

```
java_props_t *
GetJavaProperties(JNIEnv* env) { ... }
```

In this function, the system property values are read through the operating system specific APIs.

The function is called in `Java_java_lang_System_initProperties(JNIEnv *env, jclass cla, jobject props)` in the source file `./jdk/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c` which again is declared as native method in `./jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java`:

```
private static native Properties initProperties(Properties props);
```

The final initialization sequence is a bit tricky:

- `java.lang.System` has a static initializer which calls the native `registerNatives()` method.
- This native method calls `java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass()` (which is Java again).
- `initializeSystemClass()` finally calls the above mentioned native `initProperties()` method to create and initialize the system properties.