# How can you tell if your Java program is running in a GraalVM AOT context?

Tags: graalvm

I have a little Java program. I build a binary using Graal's `native-image` (i.e. GraalVM AOT aka SubstrateVM).

My program can be executed either with a Java runtime or from the native-image binary. What's the best way to tell which context I'm running in?

(This might be a bad practice in general but I believe it's inevitable/necessary in certain not-uncommon circumstances.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraalVM now provides an [API](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/sdk/src/org.graalvm.nativeimage/src/org/graalvm/nativeimage/ImageInfo.java) for checking the AOT context:

```
ImageInfo.inImageCode()
ImageInfo.inImageRuntimeCode()
ImageInfo.inImageBuildtimeCode()
ImageInfo.isExecutable()
ImageInfo.isSharedLibrary()
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: There is now an API for that. See user7983712's answer.

The way it's done in the GraalVM is by capturing the `com.oracle.graalvm.isaot` system property: it is set to `true` while building AOT images. If you combine that with the fact that static initializers run during image generation, you can use

```
static final boolean IS_AOT = Boolean.getBoolean("com.oracle.graalvm.isaot")
```

This boolean will remain true when running the native image.

This is also useful to cut-off paths that you don't want in the final output: for example if you have some code that uses a feature that SVM doesn't support (e.g., dynamic class-loading) you can predicate it with `!IS_AOT`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with GraalVM 21.2.0.r11

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaning towards checking the presence/absence of some system properties. When I print out the system properties under Graal AOT I see:

```
{os.arch=x86_64, file.encoding=UTF-8, user.home=/Users/thom, path.separator=:, os.name=Mac OS X, user.dir=/Users/thom, line.separator=
, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, file.separator=/, java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/0x/rms5rjn526x33rm394xwmr8c0000gn/T/, user.name=thom}
```

As you may notice it's fairly short and is missing all the usual `java.*` ones such as `java.class.path`. I'll omit listing the lengthy Java version and instead link to another SO listing the usual Java System properties:

[What is the full list of standard keys recognized by the Java System.getProperty() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022320/what-is-the-full-list-of-standard-keys-recognized-by-the-java-system-getproperty)

So one way to do it would seem to be to check whether one or more of the `java.*` properties are absent.

AFAIK there are no plans to set these in SubstrateVM. But System properties are mutable so one could possibly choose to fake them.

But anyway here's a way to do it:

```
def isGraalAOT = System.properties.getProperty("java.class.path") == null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use refelction to try to get a class which only exists in graalvm.

```java
  private boolean checkGraalVM() {
    try {
      Class.forName("org.graalvm.home.Version");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```